# Prove the following $A\oplus B = \neg((A\cap B) \cup \neg(A\cup B))$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I trying to prove the following statement:
$$A\oplus B = \neg((A\cap B) \cup \neg(A\cup B))$$
what I tried to do is:

1. $\neg(A\cup B)=\neg A \cap \neg B= \neg A \setminus B$
2. $\neg ((A\cap B)\cup(\neg A\setminus B))=\neg((A\setminus \neg B)\cup(\neg A\setminus B))$

this is the step I stopped.
any suggestions?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you’ve already shown (or can show) that $$X\setminus(X\cap Y)=X\setminus Y\tag{1}$$ and that $$(X\cup Y)\setminus Z=(X\setminus Z)\cup(Y\setminus Z)\;,\tag{2}$$ you can argue that

$$\begin{align*}
\neg\big((A\cap B)\cup\neg(A\cup B)\big)&=\neg(A\cap B)\cap(A\cup B)\\
&=(A\cup B)\setminus(A\cap B)\\
&=\big(A\setminus(A\cap B)\big)\cup\big(B\setminus(A\cap B)\big)\\
&=(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)\;.
\end{align*}$$

Both $(1)$ and $(2)$ are fairly easy to show, if you’ve not already done so.

Comment: Still I dont find how to do it

Comment: @Ofir: How to prove $(1)$ and $(2)$, you mean?

Comment: yes, I dont know how to prove it

Comment: @Ofir: $X\setminus(X\cap Y)=X\cap\neg(X\cap Y)=X\cap(\neg X\cup\neg Y)=(X\cap\neg X)\cup(X\cap\neg Y)=\varnothing\cup(X\setminus Y)=X\setminus Y$. See if you can do the other one yourself: start with $(X\cup Y)\setminus Z=(X\cup Y)\cap\neg Z$ and use a distributive law.